# how to set role in capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I want to change the production.rb config file

```
set :hostip,"192.168.16.37"

role :web, %w{192.168.16.37}
role :app, %w{192.168.16.37}
role :db, %w{192.168.16.37}
```

to 
    set :hostip,"192.168.16.37"

```
role :web, %w{"#{ :hostip }"}
role :app, %w{"#{ :hostip }"}
role :db, %w{"#{ :hostip }"}
```

but there is error!

```
 Exception while executing on host "#{:
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here `%w{"#{ :hostip }"}`

you can either use `%w` or `"`, but not both... :)

an basic example to show you why:

```
a = %w{" #{ 2 + 2 } " }
=> ["\"", "\#{", "2", "+", "2}", "\""]
```

You could try just using an actual string in an array (`%w` just turns a set of strings into an array of strings)

```
["#{hostip}"]
```

Comment: But how can I set the role :web by used the value of :hostip? I don't want to set the same value by 3 times.

Comment: edited... I don't know how to set the hostip... I'm only offering advice on the basic ruby :)

Answer (score 0):

It can config like this.

```
set :hostip,"192.168.16.37"
role :web, %W{#{ fetch(:hostip)}}
role :app, %W{#{ fetch(:hostip)}}
role :db, %W{#{ fetch(:hostip)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cofigure like this in a single line if you are using same `hostip` for all the roles:

```
set :hostip,"192.168.16.37"
server %w{#{fetch(:hostip)}}, :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
```